# Требуются ли тут запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Зовите кого хотите.

Решайте кто хочет.

Все кто хочет пойти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На стыке главного и придаточного предложений запятая перед "кто" всегда ставится.

*Решайте, кто хочет.*

*Все, кто хочет пойти.*

В первом примере наблюдается согласование глагола с местоимением в родительном падеже (`зовите того`, `зовите его`, `зовите кого`) и запятая не требуется.

Примеры из книг:

*Зовите Айзена, зовите солдат, зовите кого угодно!*

*И если их нужно полмиллиона, чтобы выйти из этих болот, кричите, бейтесь в тоске, зовите кого хотите — ничто вам не поможет.*

*Давайте, зовите кого хотите, в противном случае вы ответите за срыв оборонной программы нашей страны...*

*Идите, зовите кого хотите, я тоже буду жаловаться.*